# Use \apptocmd to redefine \chapter

Tags: chapters, etoolbox

I am trying to write the style name into the marginal part, e.g., `CN&CT` to come at marginal note for `\chapter` tag, for this, I tried with the code, which are follows as:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\chapter}{\protect\marginpar{CN\&CT}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{CN \& CT}

This is for test.

\end{document}
```

I've tried with `\apptocmd{\@makechapterhead}{\protect\marginnote{CN\&CT}}{}{}%` instead of `\apptocmd{\chapter}{\protect\marginpar{CN\&CT}}{}{}`, now I got the text `CN&CT` as in marginal note, but not aligned with the chapter title, can anyone advise what I did wrong in this.
please advise...

Comment: `\chapter` at the tex level takes no arguments it just starts a chain of commands that parse for *` forms and optional arguments before finally typesetting the heading, the chance that `\apptocmd{\chapter}` adds code at a useful point is rather small.

Comment: Are you trying to append the string "CN & CT" to the chapter header?

Comment: @Mico `CN&CT` is the short form of `Chapter Number & Chapter Title`, I am trying to display this as marginal tags, which helps to understand the style name easily...

Comment: then use the standard syntax `\chapter[short form]{long title}` and modify the chapter heading code to put the short form in the margin as well as (or instead of) putting it in the page  head.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to write a separate `package` which can supports all standard `class files`. e.g., `book.cls`, etc.

Comment: @MadyYuvi then definitely do as I said, not patch the top level `\chapter`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, I'm trying...

Comment: I'm not sure adding “CN&CT” in the margin would be useful in any way. What's really you want to achieve?

Comment: @egreg Much thanks for your attention. Actually I need to display the style name (`CN` refers Chapter Number, and `CT` refers Chapter TItle) to the marginal side, so every one can understand the style details. Hope I am clear...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Not at all, sorry.